# JavaScript(discord.js) TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

When i was compiling the source code of my Discord bot, i get this:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined`

This is the code:

```
const { PREFIX } = require("../config.json");

module.exports = (client, aliases, callBack) => {

if (typeof aliases === "string")

{
    aliases = [aliases];
}

client.on("message", message => {
    const { CONTENT } = message;

    aliases.forEach(alias => {
        const COMMAND = ${PREFIX}${alias};

        if (CONTENT.startsWith(`${COMMAND}`) || CONTENT === COMMAND)
        {
            console.log(Asuna is running the command "${COMMAND}"...);

            callBack(message);
        }
    });
});
```

}

Comment: So `message.CONTENT` is undefined. Verify what is in message.

Comment: so, what i'm gonna to replace here?

Comment: Can you explain what is the message ? Is it an object ? What's inside ?

Comment: What are you going to replace? What is in message? `console.log(message);`

Comment: This is the main file:

Comment: const DISCORD = require('discord.js');
const CLIENT  = new DISCORD.Client();

const TOKEN   = require("./config.json");
const COMMAND = require("./commands/commands")

CLIENT.on('ready', ready);
function ready()
{
    console.log(`${CLIENT.user.tag}! succefully logged in!`);

    COMMAND(CLIENT, "ping", message => {
        message.channel.send("pong");
    });
};

CLIENT.login(TOKEN.token);

Comment: Sorry for the indentation

Comment: Is the error here? `const COMMAND = ${PREFIX}${alias};` you should add a backtick around.

Comment: Javascript is cass sensitive, why would `content` be all caps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not getting the actual message content from the message's object (Therefore it is `undefined`).You could try to just set the message content to a constant.

```
const msg = message.content;
```

Then just use `msg` in your code.

```
if (msg.startsWith(`${COMMAND}`) || msg === COMMAND)
```